# Confused about the Definition of an Isolated Point

Tags: real-analysis

For any point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and a set $S$, $x$ is called an isolated point if $x \in S$ and $x \notin S'$, where the set $S'$ denotes the set of accumulation points. But what confuses me is that, if $x \in S$, then every neighborhood of $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $S$, but if $x \notin S'$, then for some $\epsilon > 0$, the deleted neighborhood $N^*(x;\epsilon)$ satisfies $N^*(x;\epsilon) \cap S = \varnothing$. To me, this seems like a contradiction, because the first claims that every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $S$, but the second one states that there is at least one deleted neighborhood of $x$ whose members do not belong in $S$.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Henno Brandsma has the correct answer, but it may be helpful to consider a specific example. Consider $S = (0,1) \cup \{2\}$. For neighborhoods of $2$ with radius smaller than $1$, the only intersection between $S$ and those neighborhoods is $2$ itself. The deleted neighborhoods do not contain $2$, so their intersection with $S$ is empty. $2$ is an isolated point.

Comment: Years later, I note what I have overlooked. First, every neighborhood centered at $x$ contains a point in $S$. Also, there's is a neighborhood at $x$ such that if $x$ is removed from the neighborhood, the intersection with $S$ is empty. But if $x$ is put back into the deleted neighborhood, then this neighborhood has a nonempty intersection with $S$ by the first assumption. What can we conclude? That $x \in S$. Hence the deleted neighborhood contains points different from those in $S$, except $x$ itself. I.e. $N(x;\varepsilon) \cap S = \{x\}$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more insightful definition of an isolated point of $S$ is:

There is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $N(x; \varepsilon) \cap S = \{x\}$.

This implies that $N^\ast(x; \varepsilon) \cap S = \emptyset$, indeed, so $x \notin S'$. But clearly the definition implies $x \in S$ as well.

Indeed every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $S$ (namely $x$ itself!), and for small neighbourhoods (smaller radius than $\varepsilon$) this is the *only* point this neighbourhood has in common with $S$. In the deleted neighbourhood we delete this $x$ itself, so then there are no more points in common with $S$ in the deleted neighbourhood (for those small ones).

Answer (score -2):

The first claim is wrong as $\{x\}$ may be a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Note that this is tagged as real analysis, not topology. In $\Bbb R^n, \{x\}$ does not contain an open set containing $x$..